# Unable to delete Root CA (UNIX: operation not permitted)

Tags: permissions, osx, certificates

I am trying to delete a root certificate authority from my Mac OS machine. When I try this from the 'Keychainaccess' program it asks for my password and then shows 'ecKeychainItemDelete: UNIX[Operation not permitted]'.

I've also tried to do this from the terminal with a command (with sudo) and I get the exact same error message.